# Tagging strategy for problems affecting many environments?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

I've come a cross [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13708218) where a user is adding another platform, CentOS where he encountered the problem being described by the question OP.

So, I'm trying to decide if this is a good one to approve, here's my logic:

- **True to original:** if we more want to preserve the original author's question, then this tag is irrelevant.  Do we just go with this?
- **Discoverability:** if we're optimizing for discoverability is the goal, I suppose this tag will help, but then again, we would want tags for [archlinux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/archlinux), [rhel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rhel), [gentoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gentoo), [opensuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensuse), [ubuntu-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-server)... and on and on since this permissions problem could affect any Linux OS?
- **"Correctness":**  along that line of thought, are any of these distro tags really relevant?  Nope?  So maybe we go ahead and change the original [ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu) to [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) since it's not a Ubuntu-specific problem?  Or I guess maybe it should be [unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unix)/[posix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/posix) to include macOS?

So, yea, what are your thoughts on how to approach this?  I can't decide which of these retagging strategies is the most productive; is there a standard or precedent I should know about?

Any opionions here on meta?

Comment: Just use the common denominator.

Comment: It's a matter of what the tags are actually for. Lately I've been considering people who are subscribed to certain tags in order to respond to those questions: experts on which tag are most likely to know the answer to my problem?

Comment: Add a most broad term, making sure that not only a problem but solutions are also common within the tag.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: Be careful with that though. Just because a gazillion C++ devs know details about GCC doesn't mean [tag:gcc] is appropriate on a compiler-agnostic question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: goes without saying my method is for picking tags among those otherwise appropriate for the question, not for inventing tags out of nowhere.